# Calculating view space normal instead of world space

Tags: xna, hlsl, normals, ssao

I hope you can help with this. I am currently using a deferred renderer and am trying to implement SSAO but that needs view space normals and I currently have world space normals, I am trying to work out how to convert them but keep getting stuck.

This is the main part of my vertex shaders, `instanceTransform` is either the World matrix or transpose of the instance matrix as the same code is used for instanced models as well.

```
VertexShaderOutput VertexShaderFunctionCommon(VertexShaderInput input, float4x4 instanceTransform)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output = (VertexShaderOutput)0;

    float4x4 worldViewProjection = mul(instanceTransform, ViewProjection);

    output.Position = mul(float4(input.Position.xyz,1), worldViewProjection);

    output.Depth = output.Position.zw;

    // calculate tangent space to world space matrix using the world space tangent, binormal, and normal as basis vectors
    output.TangentToWorld[0] = normalize(mul(input.Tangent, instanceTransform));
    output.TangentToWorld[1] = normalize(mul(input.Binormal, instanceTransform));
    output.TangentToWorld[2] = normalize(mul(input.Normal, instanceTransform));

    return output;
}
```

The normal calculation in the pixel shader is:

```
// read the normal from the normal map
float3 normalFromMap = tex2D(normalSampler, input.TexCoord);

//tranform to [-1,1]
normalFromMap = 2.0f * normalFromMap - 1.0f;

//transform into world space
normalFromMap = mul(normalFromMap, input.TangentToWorld);

//normalize the result
normalFromMap = normalize(normalFromMap);

//output the normal, in [0,1] space
output.Normal.rgb = NormalEncode(normalFromMap);
```

Can you help please?

Comment: Wouldn't be something like this:  `viewSpaceNormal = normalize(mul(normalize(mul(input.Normal, instanceTransform)), ViewProjection);`

Comment: Would this be in the vertex shader? I've tried swapping out the normal line but that didn't work.

Comment: Where did you use the viewSpaceNormal proposed above?